# Get the text from a text view every time it updates

Tags: java, android, dictionary, gettext

I have an app for android studio. a map app where I find my coordinates and I set them to 2 textviews. as you imagine they change when I move. The shows I want to get these values from these 2 textviews so I can set them to the marker to find me in the map fragment I have made.

```
    double lat11 = Double.parseDouble(this.lat.getText().toString());
    double long11 = Double.parseDouble(this.longi.getText().toString());


    LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat11,long11);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc)
            .title(""));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
```

As you also imagine the code above takes only the default values of the 2 textviews!

Anyone's opinion will be thankful!!

Comment: You can use [TextView#addTextChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))

Comment: Can you explain your need more? Are you taking lat lng by Edit Text from user? and take him to that place?

Comment: No but addTextChangedListener worked! thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText textview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

textview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
             //Called after before changed
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //Called after on changed
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //Called after text changed
        }
    });
```